# Radiobutton selection problem with dynamic question display

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to implement a dynamic question display feature in my React code, since I have a large number of questions with different input types, such as radiobuttons, text inputs, and dropdowns in the future. However, I'm encountering an issue with the functionality of radiobuttons.
The problem I'm facing is that when I try to select a radiobutton on the first card, nothing happens, but when I click an option on the second card, it selects the second option on the first card instead. Similarly, clicking an option on the third card doesn't trigger any action, but it selects the third option on the first card.
I suspect that the problem lies in how I'm utilizing the "name" property, but despite my efforts, I haven't been able to resolve the issue. Here's my code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

const MapSurvey = () => {
  const questions = [
    {
      questionText: "one",
      answerOptions: [
        { answerText: "One", value: 1 },
        { answerText: "Two", value: 2 },
        { answerText: "three", value: 3 },
        { answerText: "four", value: 4 },
        { answerText: "five", value: 5 },
      ],
      answerType: "radio",
    },
    {
      questionText: "Two",
      answerOptions: [
        { answerText: "One", value: 1 },
        { answerText: "Two", value: 2 },
        { answerText: "three", value: 3 },
        { answerText: "four", value: 4 },
      ],
      answerType: "radio",
    },
    {
      questionText: "three",
      answerOptions: [
        { answerText: "One", value: 1 },
        { answerText: "Two", value: 2 },
        { answerText: "three", value: 3 },
        { answerText: "four", value: 4 },
        { answerText: "five", value: 5 },
      ],
      answerType: "radio",
    },
    {
      questionText: "input",
      answerType: "text",
    },
  ];

  const [answers, setAnswers] = useState({
    answer_0: "",
    answer_1: "",
    answer_2: "",
    answer_3: "",
  });

  console.log(answers);

  const handleChange = (e) => {
    setAnswers((prev) => ({ ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }));
  };

  return (
    <div className="w-full py-[2rem] px-4 bg-white">
      <div className="max-w-[800px] w-full mx-auto text-center flex flex-col">
        <form>
          {questions.map((question, idx) => (
            <div
              key={`question-no-${idx}`}
              className="border-2 border-gray-100 shadow-xl flex flex-col p-4 my-4 mb-6 rounded-lg"
            >
              <h2 className="text-2xl font-bold text-center py-4">
                {question.questionText}
              </h2>

              {question.answerType === "radio" ? (
                <>
                  {question.answerOptions.map((option, optionIdx) => (
                    <div
                      key={`answer_${idx}_option_${optionIdx}`}
                      className="mt-3"
                    >
                      <label htmlFor={`answer_${idx}`}>
                        <input
                          type={question.answerType}
                          name={`answer_${idx}`}
                          id={`answer_${optionIdx}`}
                          value={option.value}
                          className="hidden peer"
                          onChange={handleChange}
                        />
                        <div className="px-2 py-1 rounded-lg flex justify-left items-center font-medium text-black w-full sm:w-6/12 h-10 border-2 border-gray-200 peer-hover:border-[#00df9a] peer-checked:bg-[#00df9a] peer-checked:border-none peer-checked:text-white">
                          {option.answerText}
                        </div>
                      </label>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                </>
              ) : (
                <>
                  <input
                    name={`answer_${idx}`}
                    type={question.answerType}
                    id={`answer_${idx}`}
                    className="p-2 border-2 border-gray-200 hover:border-[#00df9a] focus:border-[#00df9a] w-full sm:w-6/12 h-10 rounded-lg text-black"
                    onChange={handleChange}
                  />
                </>
              )}
            </div>
          ))}
        </form>

        {/* full button on mobile */}
        <button className="bg-black text-[#00df9a]  w-[200px] rounded-md font-medium my-6 mx-auto px-6 py-3">
          Continua
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MapSurvey;
```

What should I do to fix it?